# How to 'git pull' without SSH -or- password?

Tags: git, authentication, github

I'd like to do a `git pull` from a computer which does **NOT** have `ssh` installed. This `git pull` is going to be part of an automated process, essentially a shell script that is run periodically. This means to do the pull, I would need to store my personal GitHub password on a drive accessible to my whole company, which I'm not comfortable with.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The simplest method would be to install ssh. Is there any particular reason that's not an option? You do mention that it's not currently installed, but not why it cannot be installed at all. Note that installing ssh does not require running sshd -- your machine won't start accepting remote connections unless you tell it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by generating an API token from your account. See [this blog post](https://github.com/blog/1509-personal-api-tokens) for details.

You can use this token in place of your password when doing `git pull` over HTTPS. The big advantage of the API token is that it can later be revoked if the automated process is no longer needed.

Of course, this API token can be used to access any of your repositories. If you want to restrict access, it's probably best to make a separate Github account, and give that account access to your repository by adding it as a Collaborator on your repository.